# Rewrite external URL to internal one

Tags: node.js, apache, mod-rewrite

I found a website where they rewrite the external URL's to internal ones and with this trick they are able to avoid the same origin policy in iframes.
Here are some example how they do this:

```
External URL: http://stackoverflow.com
Internal URL: https://stackoverflow-com-m.surfly.com/HT/mj5qTc22vRI6M9mfrKULbCp//////////

External URL: http://www.facebook.com
Internal URL: https://facebook-com-m.surfly.com/www/ST/mj5qTc22vRI6M9mfrKULbCp//////////

External URL: http://www.bbc.co.uk
Internal URL: https://co-uk-m.surfly.com/bbc/www/HT/mj5qTc22vRI6M9mfrKULbCp//////////

External URL: http://www.google.de
Internal URL: https://google-de-m.surfly.com/www/ST/mj5qTc22vRI6M9mfrKULbCp//////////?gfe_rd=ctrl&ei=a5XuUueLN8yG8Qe8kIBI&gws_rd=cr
```

The `mj5qTc22vRI6M9mfrKULbCp` is a simple session variable part, but the `HT` and `ST` part is automaticaly changing and I don't know why nor what it means.

How can I rewrite an URL like this and load an external site on my own domain?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to download and process the links in the page, then display the rewritten version in the iframe.

So, for example, you have to replace:

- all full URLS (`http://...` or `https://...`)
- all protocol-only URLs (`//...`)
- all relative URLs (`/foo/bar` or `foo/bar`)

To really get it right, you also have to do this with images and scripts, including replacing all URLs in the scripts. It's a major challenge.

Also, this may well violate either the laws of some jurisdictions or the use policies of the sites in question. You should consider talking to a lawyer.